# Informatica Update Stragegy is not flagging records

Tags: informatica

Hello I have a simple mapping, that basically has a router to decided whether the record has to be inserted or updated and then use Update Strategy to flag the row.
The records were updating and inserting as expected, I had to make some modifications to the logic and did the required changes.

And now the records are no more getting flagged as an insert or an update. Below settings :
1) DD_UPDATE and DD_INSERT coded in the update strategy.
2) At session level, treat source as set to Data Driven.
3) The 2 targets set to update as update and insert respectively.

I even ran a debugger to see what is happening, the insert update records are passing through the update strategy, however the row type is set to blank when its passed to the target instance :( what could be the issue?

Comment: If you really want to figure this out then how about offer us a helping hand such as telling us exactly what you changed.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Initially there were 2 separate mappings. The first 1 reading from source 1 to target 1 and then the 2nd one from target1 to target 2. The new mapping is a marge of the first 2 original mapping so that data now loads from source 1 to target 2, so as to optimize the load time and performance. After i merged the 2 mappings and ran it multiple times the targets were indeed getting inserted and updated. But the last time i am checking it from a couple of days it is not working.

Comment: The router is basically routing the data to the insert update flows, but the Update Strategy is not able to flag the rows for an insert or an update, which mean to say the ROW TYPE is blank when a record reaches target hence only records are read, but 0 records affected in the target

Comment: I am trying this one now. Trying to delete the update strategy and re create new update strategy transaformations and recreate the session. Let me check if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Both the Update Strategy's were corrupted. deleting and recreating the update strategy's resolved the issue :) Thanks for your help!